# How does the double-dot ".." syntax work in AspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

i need to put this aop aspect to work, but i always get error 404, i need to know if this dots, after controller is right.
idk how these dots works, to acess the controller.

if can explain how the dots works.

```xml
<aop:aspect ref="permissionInterceptor">
  <aop:around
    method="invoke"
    pointcut="execution(* com.teste1.teste2.web.controller..*())
      and @annotation(com.teste1.ae.client.security.Permission)"
  />
</aop:aspect>
```

[image: Is this correct?]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I fixed your inline image link, modified the subject to better explain what you actually want to know and made the XML a bit more readable. Please learn how to format your own posts better, studying the syntax help. with regard to your question, I do agree with R.G that you ought to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The pointcut as such looks correct, so the problem must be elsewhere in your project configuration or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
execution(* com.teste1.teste2.web.controller..*())
```

would mean - the execution of any method defined in the `com.teste1.teste2.web.controller` package or one of its sub-packages

`..` is a special wild card which means any number of arguments will match. In the context of an execution pointcut it would be the current package or any sub-package of it.

Spring documentation reference : [Examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples)

*whereas (..) matches any number (zero or more) of parameters.*

The expression with `..` would work. You could verify if the controller methods gets advised when the `and @annotation(com.teste1.ae.client.security.Permission)` part is removed from the expression. If still the request results in 404 , please share the an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or Aspect code to understand the logic further.

Comment: If i remove the Permission from controller methods, it works, but if i put, i get the error 404

Comment: @johnycampos When `@Permission` is removed from the controller methods , the expression `execution(* com.teste1.teste2.web.controller..*()) and @annotation(com.teste1.ae.client.security.Permission)` will not match these methods and no advise happens.  If the flow works as expected , my guess would be that the logic related to Permission within the advice method should be reviewed.